# How to set session scope for plugin in StructureMap 2.6?

Tags: c#, session, structuremap, session-scope

How to set session scope for plugin in StructureMap 2.6?

In previous versions it is done this way:

```
For<ISomeObject>().CacheBy(StructureMap.InstanceScope.HttpSession).Use<SomeObject>();
```

However, Visual Studio displays a warning telling that the `CacheBy` method is deprecated, and that `LifecycleIs` method can be used instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax in 2.6 is:

```
c.For<ISomeObject>().LifecycleIs(new HttpSessionLifecycle()).Use<SomeObject>();
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this will do the trick:

```
    For<ISomeObject>()
        .HttpContextScoped()
        .Use<SomeObject>();
```

Comment: I'll try it, and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't save it for session scope, because I don't have the object available for the next request. Is there any difference between Session scope and HttpContext scope?

Comment: @guillegr123 - the difference between the `HttpSessionLifecycle` and the `HttpContextLifecycle` is that the `HttpContextLifecycle` caches the created objects per Http Request (each new http request gets a new object), while the `HttpSessionLifecycle` caches objects per Http Session (each user session gets a unique object that stays the same while the session lasts).